# Drop down form not saving to database

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

My haml code below is supposed to show a drop down form with three different options (QA, Staging, Production). If `contact_title` has no value or is equal to `nil` than it is set to a default value of QA in the SQLite DB. If it is set than it should show the default set value in the UI. The current code does not work. What is the most elegant way to do it?

```
%tr
          %td{:style => 'width: 30%'}
            QA or Production
          %td{:style => 'width: 70%'}
            %label{:type => 'text', :name => 'contact_title', :value => "#{@report.contact_title}"}
            .controls
              %select{:name => "contact_title"}
                %option{:selected => "selected" } QA
                %option{:select => "select" } Staging
                %option{:select => "select" } Production
                - if @report.contact_title.nil? or @report.contact_title == 0
                  %option{:selected => "selected" } QA
                  %option Staging
                  %option Production
                - if @report.contact_title == 'Staging'
                  %option{:selected => "selected" } Staging
                  %option QA
                  %option Production
                - if @report.contact_title == 'Production'
                  %option{:selected => "selected" } Production
                  %option QA
                  %option Staging
```

Comment: How do we know which will be the default set value in UI if contact_title is available? This task seems to require some JavaScript code unless I'm missing your point?

Comment: Corrected small typo above.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Model to the select_tag.

```
%tr
  %td{:style => 'width: 30%'}
    QA or Production
  %td{:style => 'width: 70%'}
    %label{:type => 'text', :name => 'contact_title', :value => "#{@report.contact_title}"}
      .controls
        =select_tag "contact[contact_title]", options_for_select(['QA', 'Staging', 'Production'])
```